# Python: Concatenate (or clone) a numpy array N times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

I want to create an MxN numpy array by cloning a Mx1 ndarray N times. Is there an efficient pythonic way to do that instead of looping?

Btw the following way doesn't work for me (X is my Mx1 array) :

```
   numpy.concatenate((X, numpy.tile(X,N)))
```

since it created a [M*N,1] array instead of [M,N]

Comment: `tile(X,N)` will do it.

Comment: The (num)Pythonic way is not to do this but to use [broadcasting](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting) instead of `tile` and `repmat` and the like.

Comment: You might not need to expand it.  If, for example, it is added or multiplied with a [M,N] or [1,N] matrix, the result will be [M,N].  `numpy` broadcasts it for you.  In fact you could use that to expand the array: `X + np.zeros(N)`.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You are close, you want to use `np.tile`, but like this:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2])
np.tile(a,(3,1))
```

Result:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2]])
```

If you call `np.tile(a,3)` you will get `concatenate` behavior like you were seeing

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Answer (score 35):

You could use [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
numpy.vstack([X]*N)
```

or [array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array) (credit to bluenote10 below):

```
numpy.array([X]*N)
```

e.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> N = 7
>>> np.vstack([X]*N)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: vstack works when we need a multidimensional array to get repeated, for example: a=[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]] becomes [[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]] with np.vstack([a]*2). The other approaches get you [[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][5,6,7,8]]

Comment: Is `vstack` even needed? Why not just `np.array([X] * N)`?

Comment: This doesn't work for N=1.  You should just use `np.array` instead of `np.vstack`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this:

```
n = 5
X = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
Y = numpy.array([X for _ in xrange(n)])
print Y
Y[0][1] = 10
print Y
```

prints:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]]

[[ 1 10  3  4]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  2  3  4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `np.vstack` is `np.array` used this way (also mentioned by @bluenote10 in a comment):

```
x = np.arange([-3,4]) # array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])
N = 3 # number of time you want the array repeated
X0 = np.array([x] * N)
```

gives:

```
array([[-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3]])
```

You can also use `meshgrid` this way (granted it's longer to write, and kind of pulling hairs but you get yet another possibility and you may learn something new along the way):

```
X1,_ = np.meshgrid(a,np.empty([N]))
```

`>>> X1` shows:

```
array([[-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3]])
```

Checking that all these are equivalent:

- meshgrid and np.array approach

  `X0 == X1`

result:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

- np.array and np.vstack approach

  `X0 == np.vstack([x] * 3)`

result:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

- np.array and np.tile approach

  `X0 == np.tile(x,(N,1))`

result:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```