# Repeat a 2D NumPy array stacking column wise into a larger 2D array, np.broadcast_to ? resize?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

The question was answered by @QuangHoang in the comments.  Using `np.tile(array, (repeats, 1))` or slower: `np.vstack([array]*repeats)`.

I have what seems to be a simple problem.  I have a NumPy array I want to replicate column-wise, and keep it a 2D array, just repeated over and over again say 50x.  I try with a `np.repeat` but the order isn't preserved - it just copies each row however many times I specify.  `broadcast_to` I can't seem to get to work either.  I'm thinking maybe I need to flatten the array with a `.reshape(-1)` then do something with it and reshape it back, but I can't seem to find the right commands. I know I can do it with `.append` and a for loop, but I'm looking for a vectorized solution.  Here's an example with the initial array and then what it should look like afterwards (I'm only repeating it 3x due to space):

```
array = np.array([(1.00,    0.80,   0.95,   0.88,   0.97,   0.85),
(0.80,  1.00,   0.87,   0.97,   0.80,   0.92),
(0.95,  0.87,   1.00,   0.85,   0.92,   0.89),
(0.88,  0.97,   0.85,   1.00,   0.85,   0.95),
(0.97,  0.80,   0.92,   0.85,   1.00,   0.88),
(0.85,  0.92,   0.89,   0.95,   0.88,   1.00)])
```

Repeat 3x:

```
array([[1.  , 0.8 , 0.95, 0.88, 0.97, 0.85],
   [0.8 , 1.  , 0.87, 0.97, 0.8 , 0.92],
   [0.95, 0.87, 1.  , 0.85, 0.92, 0.89],
   [0.88, 0.97, 0.85, 1.  , 0.85, 0.95],
   [0.97, 0.8 , 0.92, 0.85, 1.  , 0.88],
   [0.85, 0.92, 0.89, 0.95, 0.88, 1.  ],
   [1.  , 0.8 , 0.95, 0.88, 0.97, 0.85],
   [0.8 , 1.  , 0.87, 0.97, 0.8 , 0.92],
   [0.95, 0.87, 1.  , 0.85, 0.92, 0.89],
   [0.88, 0.97, 0.85, 1.  , 0.85, 0.95],
   [0.97, 0.8 , 0.92, 0.85, 1.  , 0.88],
   [0.85, 0.92, 0.89, 0.95, 0.88, 1.  ],
   [1.  , 0.8 , 0.95, 0.88, 0.97, 0.85],
   [0.8 , 1.  , 0.87, 0.97, 0.8 , 0.92],
   [0.95, 0.87, 1.  , 0.85, 0.92, 0.89],
   [0.88, 0.97, 0.85, 1.  , 0.85, 0.95],
   [0.97, 0.8 , 0.92, 0.85, 1.  , 0.88],
   [0.85, 0.92, 0.89, 0.95, 0.88, 1.  ]])
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: `np.tile(array, (3,1))` or `np.vstack([array]*3)`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang please post it as an answer so I can accept it!  Thanks for the 2nd option too as I use Pythran to compile code and my options for broadcasting are limited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Concatenate (or clone) a numpy array N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634265/python-concatenate-or-clone-a-numpy-array-n-times)

Comment: @Ali_Sh that only works for repeating a 1D array...

Comment: @Matt, The proposed codes by **Quang Hoang** are posted in the link, too, and all of them get the same result as your prepared example case (I tested). Did you test them and what is the problem? If you are seeking for another condition, it will be helpful if you provide another case.

Comment: I was waiting for him to post an answer so I could accept it, but he hasn't posted yet - @Ali_Sh